# Spring Batch waiting for lines in flat file

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I'm processing a flat file with Spring Batch but I have a problem - sometimes I must wait for stream in file - because the file is being written over a network. Now, when `FlatFileReader` reads an empty line Step has exit status COMPLETE. Is there any way to wait in Reader for the next line or maybe repeat Step with current line in an infinite loop?
I'm using Java Config so my code is:

```
@Bean
public Job importUserJob() {
    Job job = jobBuilders.get("importUserJob").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).flow(step1()).end().build();

    return job;
}
```

I found that when I use:

```
Job job = jobBuilders.get("importUserJob").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).flow(step1()).next(step1()).end().build();
```

then step1 is running in infinite loop but in each loop it reads from begginig of file.

Maybe is another way to retry step if read line is null or wait for line??
Maybe the problem is that I'm using in-memory built in hsqldb ??

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to download file in first step and process it in second step.
This is preferable because you can restart/continue processing without need to download file again and you don't encounter timeout/retry issues.

Comment: Well, the file is on the same system so I don't need download it, but the problem is another service is writing to this file (sometimes is not writing and then my Step is finished with Status COMPLETE).

Answer (score 0):

The `FlatFileItemReader` expects the file to have been completely written before it begins processing.  If the file is still being written, you should wait until it's complete before kicking off the job.

Comment: OK, I know and agree with You, but do You know any way to do it? I tried used my custom implementation of FlatFileReader and overrided method `readLine()` with: `line = this.reader.readLine();
   if (line == null) {
    wait(1000);
    return readLine();` but then Spring Batch throws Exception

Comment: Exception thrown is `at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: null
 at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)`

Comment: Honestly, I'd start by taking the code related to the message producers used in the Spring Integration file tail functionality (`OSDelegatingFileTailingMessageProducer` or `ApacheCommonsFileTailingMessageProducer`) and wrap that in an `ItemReader`.  The difficult part would be how to tell when you're done (since the file is still being written to).

Comment: Michael thank You. Well, there are two ways to do it - we can establish line count for reading and before that count limit wait for stream or establish that step is never ending. Currently I don't know how to run step in infinite loop. Maybe You know how? I'm trying use `public Step step1() {
  return stepBuilders.get("step1")
    .allowStartIfComplete(true)
    .<Log, Log> chunk(500)
    .reader(reader())
    .processor(processor())
    .writer(mongoWriter())
    .build();` but when step is ending with COMPLETE status it's not restarting.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem this way:
1. Creating SystemCommandTasklet:

```
@Bean
public Step waitStep() {
    SystemCommandTasklet tasklet = new SystemCommandTasklet();
    tasklet.setCommand("sleep 30");
    tasklet.setTimeout(31000);
    return stepBuilders.get("waitStep").tasklet(tasklet).allowStartIfComplete(true).build();
}
```

2. Creating Custom ItemReader almost the same as FlatFileItemReader but I added this:

   ```
   private String readLine() {
   if (reader == null) {
       throw new ReaderNotOpenException("Reader must be open before it can be read.");
   }

   String line = null;

   try {
       line = this.reader.readLine();
       if (line == null) {
           //this is most interesting line
           setLinesToSkip(lineCount);

           return null;
       }
       lineCount++;
       while (isComment(line)) {
           line = reader.readLine();
           if (line == null) {
               return null;
           }
           lineCount++;
       }

       line = applyRecordSeparatorPolicy(line);
   }
   catch (IOException e) {
       // Prevent IOException from recurring indefinitely
       // if client keeps catching and re-calling
       noInput = true;
       throw new NonTransientFlatFileException("Unable to read from resource: [" + resource + "]", e, line,
               lineCount);
   }

   return line;
   ```

   }

And then in my JobBuilder:

```
Job job = jobBuilders.get("importUserJob").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).flow(step1()).next(waitStep()).next(step1()).end().build();
```

This is exactly what I looked for. Now my step1 is running, and when my stream is ending the waitStep is running (waiting 30 seconds) and then step1 is running but skipping lines read earlier. And over and over again ;-)